# Redirecting a subdomain to a port; not working

Tags: nginx, dns, hosting, cloudflare

```
server {
        listen         8080 default_server;
        listen         [::]:8080 default_server;
        server_name    cad.domain.tech;
        root           /var/www/cad;
        index          index.php;

          location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
          }
        }
```

I have this in my NGINX site-availables, and when I do IP:8080 I get the webpage I put in there. However, when I do cad.domain.tech I get "server not found".

Here are my page rules and DNS settings:
[image]
[image]

Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when accessing `http://cad.domain.tech` it requests your server on port 80 by default (Port 443 if the request starts with `https://`).

So all you need to do is to redirect all incoming requests on port 80 to port 8080 in your case.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    hostname cad.domain.tech www.cad.domain.tech;
    return 301 http://cad.domain.tech:8080
}
```

This should work. `return 301` tells the requester that this is meant to be a permanent redirect.